# While loop not updating

Tags: python, while-loop, global-variables

Versions of this have been asked before but I don't get it, so I need to ask again with a simple test case. Having several functions is relevant to the actual program I'm writing, but I'm trying to understand the fault on a simple case.

```
a = 0

def test(c):
    c = c + 2
    return c
    
def test2():
    ct = 0
    while True:
        print(test(a))
        ct += 1
        if ct > 4:
            break
    
test2()
```

Running this prints '2' five times. Why wouldn't it update each time? How would I get it to update?

The same thing happens if I do something like this:

```
a = 0

def test(c):
    c = c + 2
    return c
    
def test2():
    d = a
    ct = 0
    while True:
        print(test(d))
        ct += 1
        if ct > 4:
            break
    
test2()
```

test() returns a value for d which is within the loop. So, I can't see where it would get reset back to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "Why wouldn't it update each time?"?

Comment: You are only printing the output of `test()`, not updating the variable `a` so this will always be 0 at each iteration of your loop.

Comment: when you call `test(a)` you just print the result, `a` is never updated - i.e. it stays 0, you just throw away the value returned. Note that `a` is global variable and you will need to declare as such if you want to change it inisde `test2()` because you din't pass it as argument.

Comment: An interesting question to understand your goal is: what did you expect to happen, what should update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is declare the variable, **a** to hold the value of calling the function test(a). This variable holds the value of calling the test function on itself, test(a), which to begin with is 0, then increments through each loop, assigning the variable **a** to the previous value plus 2. Declaring a Boolean variable for the while loop is considered better practise. Try play around with the code below using debug mode and follow along.

```
def test(b):
    b += 2
    return b

def test2():
    ct = 0
    a = 0
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        a = test(a)
        print(a)
        ct += 1
        if ct > 4:
            keep_going = False

test2()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't use the returned c value

```
a = 0

def test(c):
    c = c + 2
    return c


def test2():

    global a

    ct = 0
    while True:
        a = test(a)
        print(a)
        ct += 1
        if ct > 4:
            break

test2()
```

Result

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You never update a so it will print the same value every time

```
a = 0
def test(c):
    c = c + 2
    return c
    
def test2():
    ct = 0
    while True:
        print(test(a))# "a" is not updated
        ct += 1
        if ct > 4:
            break
    
test2()
```